# simple regex to splice out text in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using ruby and I want to splice out a piece of a string that matches a regex (I think this is relatively easy, but I'm having difficulty)

I have several thousand strings that look like this (to varying degrees)

```
my_string = "adfa <b>weru</b> orua fklajdfqwieru ofaslkdfj alrjeowur woer woeriuwe  <img src=\"/images/abcde_111-222-333/111-222-333.xml/blahblahblah.jpg\" />"
```

I would like to splice out the **/111-222-333.xml** (the value of this changes from string to string, but suffice it to say is that I want to remove the piece between 2 forward slashes that contains *something.xml*.

my hope was to find a match like this

```
my_match = my_string.match(/\/.+?\.xml\//)
```

but this actually captures  `"/b> orua fklajdfqwieru ofaslkdfj alrjeowur woer woeriuwe  <img src=\"/images/abcde_111-222-333/111-222-333.xml/"`

I assumed that **.+?** would match what I am looking for, but it seems like it starts with the first forward slash that it finds (even though it's non-greedy) and then expands forward to the ".xml").

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

TKS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/\/[^\/]+\.xml\//`. This will force the parts between the slashes to be non-slashes, something your original regex does not. The original looks for the first slash, then matches anything until it finds the first `.xml/`. A greedy match there would look for the last `.xml/`, which doesn't make a difference in your case.

Comment: this makes sense.  thank you.  basically...find stuff between 2 forward slashes that does not *itself* contain forward slashes